# A set of unique lists

Tags: python, list, set

I have a lists of lists, e.g.:

```
[['4bb', '3bb', '3', '1', '2', '4b', '4'],
 ['4bb', '3bb', '1', '3', '2', '4b', '4'],
 ['4bb', '3bb', '1', '2', '3', '4b', '4'],
 ['4bb', '1', '3bb', '3', '2', '4b', '4'],
 ['4bb', '1', '3bb', '2', '3', '4b', '4']]
```

I want to create a list of shorter lists - only the three rightmost elements of each list, such that the elements are unique, e.g:

```
[['2', '4b', '4'],
 ['3', '4b', '4']]
```

I tried to use "set" but this doesn't work because a list is not hashable.

Comment: Order of sublists in the new list does not matter?

Comment: @AnandSKumar order does not matter.

Comment: Oh ok, then the answers below should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the order of sublists in the new list does not matter, You can use a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) instead of `list` to store in the [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) . `tuple`s are hashable and hence can be added to a set.

Example using `set comprehension` (for Python 2.7+) -

```
setlst = {tuple(x[-3:]) for x in lst}
newlst = list(map(list, setlst))
```

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with `set()` as `set([<list comp>])` for versions of Python where set comprehension is not supported.

Demo -

```
>>> lst = [['4bb', '3bb', '3', '1', '2', '4b', '4'],
...  ['4bb', '3bb', '1', '3', '2', '4b', '4'],
...  ['4bb', '3bb', '1', '2', '3', '4b', '4'],
...  ['4bb', '1', '3bb', '3', '2', '4b', '4'],
...  ['4bb', '1', '3bb', '2', '3', '4b', '4']]
>>>
>>> setlst = {tuple(x[-3:]) for x in lst}
>>> newlst = list(map(list, setlst))
>>> newlst
[['2', '4b', '4'], ['3', '4b', '4']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
map(list, set(map(tuple, a)))
```

The most inner `map` maps the lists to tuple, and since it's hashable, you can apply `set` in it. Then you simply map it back to `list`.